# Discord.js Error: Cannot find module './token.json'

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm getting this error: `Error: Cannot find module './token.json'` even though I have installed token

Comment: You should tag the question as Discord.js is a Node.js module. Maybe more people could help you.

Comment: Show your code also

Answer (score 0):

One single `./` means you go out of the File
`../` mean you go out of the Folder
`./..` means you go out of Parent Folder and so on. You could have maybe showed us your File Tree. This would have been made a lot easier for me.